# License online check on windows installer

Tags: c#, windows, windows-installer

I am studying a solution to create a "developer" version of my project (asp.net application) with source code and license key.
In order to protect the code, I want to create a windows installer that checks the license key from an online API and, if valid, edit some configurations on installation phase. Is there possible license check with API?

If not, I think that I must create a different installer per customer that wants this version.

Comment: You can use a "custom action" feature (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/custom-actions) to call your API and then abort or continue installation depending on call results. Also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387269/calling-a-web-service-from-wix. By the way, despite of license check, anybody can just unpack msi and see your code (except if you will use some additional security mechanisms)

Answer (score 0):

Paid setup authoring tools include such a functionality, but you'll need to set up the server-side code, following a tutorial like the one below - check out the video at the end of the article:

- [How do I configure server-side serial number validation?](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-server-side-sn.html)

Such tools provide the built-in support in the installer, so you don't need to write custom actions to communicate with the webserver. All the code you need to write/configure, is on the server. If you have web dev experience you should get this done in a few hours.

Disclaimer: I work on the team building the product recommended in the above tutorial.